# Does anyone have an idea on how to create NameSpaces in Hyperledger FireFly?

Tags: hyperledger

Does anyone have an idea on how to create NameSpaces in Hyperledger FireFly?

Firefly documentation says, we can have multiple namespaces; however I am not able to find steps to create it...

There is a reference about configuration for namespaces:
https://hyperledger.github.io/firefly/reference/namespaces.html

but it's not giving a complete idea to be able to create one...

Can someone provide steps?

Answer (score 0):

The page you reference (nowadays?) shows the configuration to create one. It also mentions the following in the end of the paragraph [Config Restrictions](https://hyperledger.github.io/firefly/reference/namespaces.html#config-restrictions):

> All namespaces must be called out in the FireFly config file in order
> to be valid. Namespaces found in the database but not represented in
> the config file will be ignored.

This implies that all namespaces must be pre-configured and unfortunately it seems they can't be created on-the-fly or via a REST call.

Comment: But I must say, trying to configure it, it is lacking crucial information on where to configure these namespaces exactly...